# Geth Failed RLPx handshake error EOF when trying to connect static node

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm currently attempting to connect nodes and encountering two errors:

1. The node is still using the `127.0.0.0` IP address, which is localhost, instead of detecting my public IP for other nodes to connect.
2. When trying to connect between nodes, I receive the following error message: `TRACE[03-01|04:24:03.318] Failed RLPx handshake addr=127.0.0.1:30303 conn=staticdial err=EOF`. I assume this is because the IP is local, but even if it weren't, it still results in a timeout.

What could be causing this problem?

I'm running this setup in a VM, with one VM located in Asia and the other in Europe, which are different regions. I've attempted to connect them using both `admin.addPeer()` and admin.addTrustedPeer(), both of which return `true`, but the nodes still aren't connected.

Comment: Can you provide more details? For example the command lines used to launch the nodes. Are the VMs visible to each other? What about proxys and firewalls? If I remember correctly the nodes try to discover their external IP but it could fail. There should be a command line switch to provide the external IP to the node.